# How to get a collection from firestore which is a Regular Expression?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

[database collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cDjq.png)

I want to get all the docs matching the regular expressions from firestore and here's the code which I am trying

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umguq.png)

```
import firebase from "../firebase";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Result = (props) => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { exam, category, councelling, branch, gender, rank } = state.state;

  const regex = RegExp("^[A-Z]{*}${branch}$");
  const db = firebase.firestore();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = db
        .collection(exam)
        .doc("2019-2020")
        .collection("RankAnalysis")
        .doc(regex);
      const data = await res.get();
      const dataVal = data.data();
      console.log(dataVal, "sdfds");
      console.log(data.data());
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{exam}</h1>
      <h1>{branch}</h1>
      <h1>{category}</h1>
      <h1>{gender}</h1>
      <h1>{councelling}</h1>
      <h1>{rank}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Result;
```

The deal is to get all docs matching a regular expression(the last word should end with my branch variable) and further implement a query but I am getting this error

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): s.indexOf is not a function

Comment: Possible typo, did you mean to use string templating in "inject" the branch name, i.e. `RegExp(\`^[A-Z]{*}${branch}$\`)`?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore doesn't support native indexing or search for text fields in documents. Additionally, downloading an entire collection to search for fields client-side isn't practical.

More on: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in Cloud Firestore to do so.
The best solution would be using Algolia or any other search engines as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search).

Could you specify your use case? Maybe what the 'branch' or so means? There may be a workaround for that. You could always use queries to find results with a specific branch.

```
db.collection('results').where('branch', '==', 'a branch').get()
```